# Separating with ","?

Tags: ios, xcode

I iterate trough an Array like that.

```
NSArray *array = [[currentRaum raumattribute] allObjects];

    NSString *compositeString = [ [ NSString alloc ] init ];
    for( Raumattribute *attr in array ){
        compositeString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",compositeString, attr.attributname ];
    [raumAttributLabel setText:compositeString];
```

I want a output like that ---->   Cat,Dog,Mouse

But if i do this:

```
compositeString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,",compositeString, attr.attributname ];
```

the output is Cat,Dog,Mouse,

or if i do this like that:

```
compositeString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",compositeString, attr.attributname ];
```

the output its ,Cat,Dog,Mouse

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using array's `valueForKey:` and `componentsJoinedByString:` methods:

```
NSString * compositeString =  [[array valueForKey:@"attributname"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

`valueForKey:` will create array of attributname values for each array element

`componentsJoinedByString:` will join those values into one string separated by commas